# Rehydrating state with no initial object store

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

Title pretty much explains my issue, I'm persisting state else where in my component that stores an object in [`localforage`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/localforage). The object gets stored fine later in the component, but IF I'm coming in the component/page for the first time there is no store available to retrieve from localforage.

I'm rehydrating in `componentDidMount` but if there's no store to update a state value with it throws an error and the component crashes.

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    localforage
      .getItem("uriStore")
      .then(localforageStore => {
        // This code runs once the value has been loaded
        // from the offline store.
        console.log("localforage store in cDM ---> ", localforageStore);
        this.setState({
          Uris: localforageStore
        });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log("Error -->", error)
  }
```

So how can I handle the case when there's no data in the store?

Comment: I don't understand the problem, what's going wrong when there is no initial object stored?

Comment: on mount an error is thrown saying `Uris` is null

Comment: Your state should have a default value.

Comment: @GG. Initial state value is `Uris: {}`

Comment: Then maybe `this.setState({ Uris: localforageStore || {} });`?

Comment: Good point, I will check this out. It was strange because I was setting the object to a key store before I realized I needed to rehydrate state, so the store already existed in `localforage` before I tried to rehydrate in `cDM`. Then late I cleared the cache so the store was wiped and that's when I found this issue.